# Suppressing PhantomJS error output

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I'm running Cucumber tests in Capybara with Poltergeist and I'm seeing the PhantomJS error for Function.prototype.bind in some of my tests. (The shim isn't working for some reason.) I'd like to suppress the output from phantom.

I've tried

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  options = {
    :debug => false,
    :js_errors => false,
    :phantomjs_options => ['--debug=no'],
  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

but I'm still seeing the stacktrace. Is there a different way to tell phantom that I don't want to see any exceptions in STDOUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I ended up solving this by setting :phantomjs_logger to Logger.new("/dev/null")</s>

Well apparently dumping output to null makes poltergeist timeout a lot.

Using StringIO.new does work, however.

Comment: Most likely, `StringIO.new` is going to accumulate memory (take more and more of it). If you've got something long-running, you might prefer something along the lines of: `Class.new do def puts s; end end.new`. Also, you might want to set `logger` option as well.